# Gorm one to one relation ship 2 foreignkeys refering one go model?

Tags: postgresql, go, orm, foreign-keys, go-gorm

Receiver uint            `gorm:"not null",json:"receiver"`
Sender   uint            `gorm:"not null",json:"sender"`
User     User            `gorm:"foreignKey:Receiver,Sender"

my model loos like this and sender and reciver refers to user model when i migrate it throughs an error how do i solve that

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your question, you have an object that has a User reference. Then there is a Receiver and a Sender which refer to this User. Since both seem to point to the same user one is not necessary. I guess you are trying to create an object like this:

```
type Obj struct {
    Receiver uint
    ReceiverUser User `gorm:"foreignKey:Receiver"`
    Sender uint
    SenderUser User `gorm:"foreignKey:Sender"`
}
```

Answer (score 0):

create different relation ships the relations should be unique the above answer should work and creates fk_reciver ans fk_sender belongs_to relation ships using id as a reference use it like this

`type Model struct {
Receiver uint
ReceiverUser User gorm:"foreignKey:Receiver"
Sender uint
SenderUser User gorm:"foreignKey:Sender"
}`